# When error appear it retry same username on Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

My Code :

```
import requests
from time import sleep
from colorama import Fore

file = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('myusername.txt')]
count = 0

URL = "https://127.0.0.1/ajax/attempt/"
headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36'}

for username in file:
    count += 1
    data = {
        'firstname':'firstname',
        'lastname' : 'lastname',
        'username': username
    }
    r = requests.post(url = URL, headers=headers, data = data)
    responde = r.text
    print(responde)
    if ('error_type' in responde):
        print('{}[+]Trying ({}/{}) -{}{} Username: {} Taken{}'.format(Fore.WHITE, count, len(file), Fore.RESET, Fore.RED, username, Fore.RESET))
    elif ('account_valid' in responde):
        print('{}[+]Trying ({}/{}) -{}{} Username: {} Available{}'.format(Fore.WHITE, count, len(file), Fore.RESET, Fore.GREEN, username, Fore.RESET))
    elif ('Please wait a few minutes before you try again.' in responde):
        sleep(30)
        print('{}[+]Waiting 30Sec for recheck ...{}'.format(Fore.YELLOW, Fore.RESET))
```

When My Program see in `responde` `Please wait a few minutes before you try again` it wait 30 sec and Retry .

but the Problem is, it bypass that username when server busy and do try it for next user .

i want when server busy appear after it wait, Retry again with same user and go on ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add another loop that repeats the `request` until a condition is met (I think in your case when it enters either the `if` or first `elif`:

```
for username in file:
    count += 1
    data = {
        'firstname':'firstname',
        'lastname' : 'lastname',
        'username': username
    }
    redo = True
    while redo:
        r = requests.post(url = URL, headers=headers, data = data)
        responde = r.text
        print(responde)
        if ('error_type' in responde):
            redo=False #Terminate while loop
            print('{}[+]Trying ({}/{}) -{}{} Username: {} Taken{}'.format(Fore.WHITE, count, len(file), Fore.RESET, Fore.RED, username, Fore.RESET))
        elif ('account_valid' in responde):
            redo=False #Terminate while loop
            print('{}[+]Trying ({}/{}) -{}{} Username: {} Available{}'.format(Fore.WHITE, count, len(file), Fore.RESET, Fore.GREEN, username, Fore.RESET))
        elif ('Please wait a few minutes before you try again.' in responde):
            # redo=True stays and while loop is executed again
            sleep(30)
            print('{}[+]Waiting 30Sec for recheck ...{}'.format(Fore.YELLOW, Fore.RESET))
```